# С какого языка можно "войти в программирование"?

Tags: веб-программирование, backend

Всем доброго времени суток, прошу вас помочь мне.
Мне, как человеку мало знающему о самом понятии программирования очень сложно выбрать направление.
Может вы подскажете с чего мне лучше начать?

Что хочу изучать я сам даже не знаю т.к. не знаю кто сейчас более востребован на рынке труда.

Сам прошел курс HTML и CSS, могу даже сказать что знаю этих два языка на уровне выше среднего. Но веб-разработка мне как то не очень зашла, по крайней мере фронт-энд, хотя может я даже не почувствовал еще всех прелестей... кто знает..
Английский у меня на хорошем уровне, жил 6 лет в Дании.

Comment: Определитесь сначала с областью, которая была бы вам интересна, а потом уже думайте о языке. Если совсем все плохо, можно выучить какую-нибудь классику вроде `c`/`c++`/'c#'/'java', получите общие сведения о работе с памятью, структурах данных. Но объективного ответа на ваш вопрос дать нельзя, потому что для каждой области существуют свои языки, и подсказать что-то, что покроет их все, невозможно.

Comment: Веб-разработка — это вообще-то JavaScript. А HTML и CSS — это вообще не программирование.

Answer (score 1):

Я изучал много языков програмирования(python,php,c++,C#,js) в том числе языки разметки и стилей html и css

Я посоветовал бы начинать или с С или с python, так как на С похожи многие языки и если начинать с С(как сделал в свое врямя я) то вы сможете больше понимать о типах переменых их значении и т.д. Python потому что этот язык очень дружелюбен к новичкам.

Если для веб разработки то тогда нужно учить и php и js

Comment: Почему по вашему C++ не дружелюбен к новичкам?

Comment: @Любитель как может быть дружелюбен к новичкам язык, который даже к профессионалам не дружелюбен?)

Comment: @andreymal хорошая полемическая уловка :) От себя могу сказать, что переключение на C++ с помощью Алекса Эллейна хорошо развило мои навыки.

Comment: С++ очень и очень прост. И с каждой версией всё проще, но при этом оставаясь настолько же мощным как и был. Плюсы недружелюбен не к профессионалам, а, простите, к.. ммм.. назовём их вежливо рассеянными людьми. В основном не любят плюсы за ручное управление памятью. Но я бы назвал эту возможность крайне полезной, особенно когда не хелловорд пишется, а производительное приложение.

Comment: @Sheridan как жаль, что подавляющее большинство C++ программистов являются.. ммм.. назовём их вежливо рассеянными людьми :( Ах, если бы были программисты были не рассеянными — как прекрасен был бы мир без Heartbleed, выполнения произовльного кода без авторизации через RDP, убийства биоса хоста изнутри виртуальной машины, возможности майнинга биткоинов на выключенных компьютерах и вирусов в png-картинках!..

Comment: @Любитель называть «навыками» зазубривание костылей для обхода неочевидных опасностей C++ — ну такое.

Comment: @andreymal Осталось понять как именно это относится к плюсам

Comment: @Sheridan код, написанный "рассеянным" программистом, не должен компилироваться вообще. В C/C++ он не только компилируется, но и доезжает до продакшена в виде этих самых Heartbleed. В нормальных языках сделать Heartbleed в safe-коде невозможно в принципе - компилятор не скомпилирует. (А даже если скомпилирует, то упадёт при рантаймовой проверке)

Comment: @andreymal вы с js перепутали :)

Comment: @Sheridan js хотя бы не сливает злоумышленнику всю память процесса просто так.

Comment: https://github.com/indutny/heartbleed

Answer (score 1):

На рынке востребованы не столько языки, сколько специалисты. Попробуйте пописать на всём что подвернётся под руку. На C++, на питоне, на swift, на js, php, перле, руби, шарп и так далее. Выберите себе то, что больше понравится и начните двигаться в этом направлении.

Таким образом вы не только осознанно выберите себе язык, но и будете иметь представление о других языках, сможете разобраться в чужом коде.

Ну и вообще, изучать и работать только в одном языке в современном мире практически невозможно. Как минимум нужно знать один основной язык и два-три вспомогательных. Например, питон - основной язык, sql, bash - вспомогательные. Или js - основной а html, css - вспомогательные и так далее.

И да, html и css это языки разметки.